# How to get previous element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I've got something like this:

```
<div class='item'>some code</div>
<div class='item current'>some code</div>
<div class='item'>some code</div>
```

The next element I can get by `document.querySelector(".item.current + .item")`. That's great and works fine but.. How can I get to the previous element?

Comment: Here's your answer: [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 10):

You can get the previous element "sibling" with the `previousElementSibling` property. For example

```
document.querySelector('.item.current').previousElementSibling
```

Would return the first element,  `<div class="item"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

```
document.querySelector(".item.current").previousElementSibling
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `document.querySelector(".item.current").previousElementSibling`.

Answer (score 0):

There [is no "previous sibling" selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) that you can use directly.

You can use javascript to select it using `document.querySelector(".item.current").previousElementSibling`